# How to update the current user (Accounts)

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using `Accounts` (`accounts-hithub`).
Now this is working fine, but now I would like to update the current users.

I've tried things like

```
Accounts.update({_id: Meteor.user()._id}, {...});
```

Which gives an error, Accounts doesn't have a method `update`
So I tried to create a users collection

```
Users = new Meteor.Collection('users');
```

This is also not allowed, it gives me the following error:

```
Error: A method named '/users/insert' is already defined
```

So how do I update the current user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User details are in the `Meteor.users` collection. So you can edit user details using `Meteor.users.update()` (http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users).